# Why is my shared library not found?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I'm trying to compile an example program that links to the shared library produced by [Sundown](https://github.com/tanoku/sundown). I'm compiling the program like so.

```
$ gcc -o sd sundown.c -L. -lsundown
```

Yet, when I run it I get the following error.

> ./sd: error while loading shared libraries: libsundown.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

The output of `ls` is.

```
$ ls
libsundown.so  libsundown.so.1  sundown.c  sd
```

Why is the shared library not found by `ld`?

Comment: add `.` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable?

Comment: @JonLin Wow. That actually worked. But why does the `-L` flag not work?

Comment: -L tells gcc where to look for a library so that it can link, not the compiled binary

Comment: @JonLin I plan on distributing the compiled binary. How can I do so that the library can be distributed without forcing people to edit their `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short solution:

add `.` (or whatever it is from your `-L` flag) to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. When you run `sd`, it'll look for libraries in the standard places and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Note that since you've added `.`, this will only work if you run `sd` from the same directory libsundown.so is in.

> I plan on distributing the compiled binary. How can I do so that the library can be distributed without forcing people to edit their LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

You should install libsundown.so in one of the standard places, like /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib. You can do that with an installer or a make file, or something as simple as a INSTALL or README that tells the user to stick the libraries there and ensure the permissions are set to something sensible.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help, this has been confusing me for days. =P

Answer (score 2):

On Centos systems with /usr/lib and /usr/lib64, if you install 64-bit libs manually into /usr/lib then at runtime, the library may not be visible even though at build time it is visible (I used autotools and it was able to find my zopfli library from /usr/lib without any problem).  When I execute the my_binary that links to /usr/lib/libzopfli.so.1  I got

```
libzopfli.so.1 => not found
```

After moving libzopfly.so.1 from /usr/lib to /usr/lib64, then everything works fine.