# How to set OpenCL runtime environment on ARM target Board?

Tags: arm, opencl, driver, nvidia

I want to run the OpenCL programme on my [target Board (CARMA)](http://www.seco.com/prods/usa/category/discontinued-products/carma-devkit.html) having Nvidia Quadro 1000M. But when i run the project on board it gives an error saying that

> libOpenCL.so is not found

Then i understand it missing runtime libOpenCL.so so I have downloaded graphics driver from [nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) (NVIDIA-Linux-armv7l-gnueabihf-361.45.11.run)
 and successfully installed on target but I have no success.

Please tell me how to set runtime environment to run opencl on ARM board? Or

How to make available libOpenCL.so on target?

Comment: This question isn't related to OpenCL itself. Add path to your OpenCL library to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111293/why-is-my-shared-library-not-found

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan I don't have library at my target.....so it's not possible to set library path.

Comment: You say that you've successfully installed Nvidia driver on your board, but you don't have libOpenCL.so anywhere in file system, right?

Comment: Yes actually... I have given link also from where I have downloaded ..